# Kicad: How do just drill holes and have solder pads for external connections to a PCB?

Tags: pcb, schematics, kicad

I'm having trouble finding this, so my apologies if this is a stupid question. I am creating a PCB that where my schematic has 5-6 pots. These pots will be mounted on an external panel, not the PCB. All I need the PCB to have is a few holes and solder pads that can accept wires from that run to the external panel.

Is there a footprint I can use for a pot that just has three holes close together? I can seem to find a generic way to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: Create a footprint that does what you need?  Or create a footprint that has a single pad and hole and place those as you need.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I typically use the footprint for a 0.1 inch pitch "pin header".  You can then use either male or female connector strips, or just solder wires directly to the pads if you don't need to use a connector.  But using the header/connector provides a convenient place to show where the external connections are in the schematic and on the board. But it does not compel you to actually use connectors (or headers) if you don't need them.

If you want to use connectors, the male pin headers are available in strips of ~40 pins and you can just snap off however many pins you need.  And you can make female connectors (with however many pins) yourself.  I find it rather compact, convenient, and low-cost solution.

[image]